# Selecting products' description translations for invoice report

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm-2011, ssrs-2012, dynamics-crm-2016

I have translated my product catalog by exporting and importing field translations and I was thinking that in my custom SSRS invoice report, I could explicitly select the strings I want depending on a value of a certain field on the account that's associated to the invoice (ie: a "french" account would list the french translation of the product, same goes for an "english" account).

Unfortunately, I'm trying to find these translations in the `Filtered*` views, but I'm not seeing them. Are they only available in the physical tables ? (which I assume are not accessible to non-sysadmin users, which is a problem security wise...)

Is there any work around or I'll have to create a custom field on the `Product` entity and put the translations there ? (ie: "Name", then "Name (french)" as a custom field)

I've found `FilteredStringMap` but that's only for option sets I believe.